# Why does Python's `any` function not return True or False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, any

If I try

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> a = any(x < 0 for x in b)  
>>> print(a)
```

it doesn't return `True` or `False`.

It returns

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbd62129ab0>
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is this all of your code? As-is, it does produce this output.

Comment: Two hundred quatloos says that you're working with `numpy.any`, not Python's `any`.  `numpy.any` doesn't play well with generators.

Comment: On python 3.5 and 2.7 you code prints `False`.  But if I use `numpy.any` it gives your output.  Use `a = __builtins__.any(x<0 for x in b)`.  This is what happens when you `import *`.

Comment: @DSM and, once again, clear example why wildcard imports sucks and namespaces actually matters (a lot).

Comment: I've edited the image into the question. Please copy-paste the terminal output directly, rather than giving a link to an image in future.

Comment: Sometimes, it's not easy to tell that a `from numpy import *` has happened. I'm a long-time python user and rely heavily on numpy, and I just made this mistake myself, having started python as `ipython --pylab`. So I can understand how this might have happened...

Comment: Yes. You're right. That's because of pylab.

Comment: With the `numpy.any` diagnosis this does not need to be put on hold.

Comment: @hpaulj The *question* still hasn’t improved at all. Even if we know now from the comment thread (which is also difficult to follow as of right now).

Comment: All it is missing is the `from pylab import *`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a `numpy.any()` instead of the built-in `any()`. Most probably you have `from numpy import any` or `from numpy import *`, which causes this behavior.

**Why that happens?**

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html), `any` tests if any element evaluates the condition. However, if you look into the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1892-L1970), it actually returns a `asanarray()` result which is a `generator`.

**How to avoid it?**

It is always a good idea to import only `scope` rather than the method itself, like so: `import numpy as np`

:)

**UPDATE 1**

Personally, I have never used `iPython`, but thanks to comments by @Praveen and @hpaulj, if you use `--pylab` flag with `ipython`, you will see the same behavior, and you can turn that behavior off - never knew it! :)))

Comment: And this is a good example why the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

Comment: Yep - saw your comment after editing the answer :)))

Comment: You could also run into this issue if you started python as `ipython --pylab`, as many scientific programming tutorials will instruct you to.

Comment: @Praveen - I didn't know that, just checked :) I guess that all the modules are imported automatically. I wonder if it might cause any problems/conflicts with the built-in functions.

Comment: It is possible to turn off the `*` imports with `--pylab` - but it requires a flag in the setup (or option in the command line).

Answer (score 2):

it returns false

```
 >> b = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
 >>> b
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 >>> a = any(x<0 for x in b)
 >>> a
 False
 >>> print(a)
 False
```