# Python any() condition not returning correct output

Tags: python, boolean, logic, any

I cannnot find out why any() is not returning True here. I think it may have something to do with numpy.any instead of the builtin any() function, as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356081/why-does-pythons-any-function-not-return-true-or-false). However, I've also tried calling any as __builtins __.any, but it still returns False.

import numpy as np

```
import numpy as np
VCI=20
anom_con = [10,20,35,50]
print VCI<anom_con[3]
print VCI<any(anom_con)
```

returns:

```
True
False
```

Interestingly, I am also using any() elsewhere in my code, and it works fine there:

```
z=-0.668
z_con = [-2,-1.5,-1,1,1.5,2]
print z < any(z_con)
```

returns:

```
True
```

Comment: Because `any(anom_con)` evaluated first to `True`. So you compare `20 < True` which is `False`. And `True` is stored as an integer `1`, so  `-0.668 < True` is actualy `True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`any` works as expected, just not as *you* expected it to work.

`any` returns `True` as soon as it finds an element which evaluates to `True`. In case of numbers it means it will return `True` as soon as it finds a non-zero element.

What you meant to write is `any(num > VCI for num in anom_con)` in the first example and `any(num > z for num in z_con)` in the second example.

The fact that

```
z = -0.668
z_con = [-2,-1.5,-1,1,1.5,2]
print z < any(z_con)
```

outputs a "correct" output is purely coincidental. It prints `True` because:

1. `any(z_con)` evaluates to `True` (because `z_con` has at least one non-zero number)
2. `z < True` evaluates to `True` because `True` has the underlying value of 1, and `-0.668 < 1` is `True`.

Comment: in addition: as `any(anom_con) == True == 1` the comparision `VCI<any(anom_con)` is seen as  `20 < 1`.

Comment: That's what I get for not accurately reading the docs. Thank you, I'll accept when the 6 minutes are past

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thanks, I added an explanation that the second example "works" is purely coincidental